# How to define multiple logback configuration for different environments in Play framework?

Tags: logging, playframework, logback

I've read the [doc](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/SettingsLogger) on how to add logback.xml file to Play framework. I need a way to be able to define something like

- logback-prod.xml
- logback-qa.xml
- logback-dev.xml
- logback-{some_name}.xml

And specify some_name when starting PlayFramework.

Comment: -Dlogger.resource=logback-{some_name}.xml ?

Comment: @VM4 will try it

Answer (score 0):

You can supply this value at runtime when running your code on terminal

```
sbt logger.resource=logback-qa.xml run
```

Play documentation link for modifying logger behaviour: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/SettingsLogger

Answer (score -1):

Keep the default *logback.xml* for during the development, this way when you debug you don't need to supply additional flags.  For the QA, Production, and other environments, provide *-Dconfig.file* parameters.  Here is an example of a bash script to start an app in the production environment specifying the location of the configuration and the log XML:

```
#!/bin/bash

APP_DIR=code
APP_DIR_CONF=code_conf

echo Starting application

/var/www/$APP_DIR/bin/$APP_DIR -Dconfig.file=/var/www/$APP_DIR_CONF/production.conf -Dlogger.file=/var/www/$APP_DIR_CONF/logback-prod.xml &

sleep 5

echo Done!
```

For in-depth discussion, please check out *The Definitive Guide to Launching a Play/Scala Web Application*.  The page includes references to LineDrop's GitHub repository which includes the deployment scripts:

https://code.linedrop.io/guides/The-Definitive-Guide-to-Launching-a-Scala-Play-Web-Application/Deploying-the-Application